# MySQL - Error while connecting to MySQL Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I use MySQL connector (Python3) and I would Like to upload in a existing Table  values of an CSV just one Column. I created a new column in the DB with:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD `TEST` TEXT;
```

Now I created a python Query what is the Problem there?

```
#stvk is my dataframe
for i,row in stvk_u.iterrows():
       print(row["datas_of_other_csv"])
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (TEST) VALUES(%s)",tuple(row["datas_of_other_csv"]))
```

But I get the error:

Error while connecting to MySQL Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Can I do not just insert into a existing table? I do not see what is wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The statement requires exactly one parameter, while you provide > 1 parameter.

tuple function splits a string and returns a tuple of characters:

```
$ python3 -c "print(tuple('foo'))"
('f', 'o', 'o')
```

Correct would be:

```
cursor.execute(statement, (row["datas_of_other_csv"],))  # note the comma at the end of tuple
```

Comment: Interessting that did not work! But this works partially:
```cursor.execute("UPDATE Test SET name = %s",(e,))``` Insert to give me an error about an other column! With this version, only the last element is taken i do not know why!

Comment: Since you didn't tell us the output of `print(row["datas_of_other_csv"])` I had to use my crystal ball, assuming it is a string value.